# OpenTelemetry: Context propagation using messaging (Artemis)

Tags: quarkus, activemq-artemis, open-telemetry

I wrote some micro-services using Quarkus that communicate via Artemis. Now I want to add OpenTelemetry for tracing purpose.

What I already tried is to call service B from service A using HTTP/REST. Here the trace id from service A is automatically added to the header of the HTTP request and used in service B. So this works fine. In Jaeger I can see the correlation.

But how can this be achieved using Artemis as messaging system? Do I have to (manually) add the trace id from service A into the message and read it in service B to setup somehow the context (don't know whether this is possible)? Or is there possibly an automatism like for HTTP requests?

I would appreciate any assistance.
I have to mention at this point that I have little experience with tracing so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no quarkus, quarkiverse extension or smallrye lib that provides integration with Artemis and OpenTelemetry, yet.

Also, OpenTelemetry massaging spec is being worked at the moment, because the correct way to correlate sent, received messages and services is [under definition at the OTel spec level](https://github.com/open-telemetry/oteps/pull/220).

However, I had exactly the same problem as you and did a manual instrumentation that you can use as inspiration: [quarkus-observability-demo-activemq](https://github.com/brunobat/quarkus-observability-demo/tree/main/quarkus-observability-demo-activemq)

It will correlate the sent service as parent of receiving end.

Comment: Thank you very much already! I thought about a more or less similar approach, but didn't know the intrumenter. I will have a deeper look into it. Again, thank you!

Comment: How do you handle the baggage information here? I can see, that the baggage is set correctly using REST (Baggage.current() returns values). Do I have to re-set the values in a new baggage or are they somehow accessible from the parent span? At the moment I don't understand the connection beteen the context or span and the baggage values.

Comment: Unlike OpenTracing, on OpenTelemetry, Baggage is independent signal and totally different from the span. See: https://opentelemetry.io/docs/concepts/signals/baggage/
Therefore, for Artemis, you will need to manually set and retrieve the baggage.